# OpenERP - modules import error

Tags: python, odoo, add-on, python-import

I'm using openerp without installation - just running it from source:

1. get openobject-server, openobject-addons and openerp-web from launchpad
2. place to /opt/openerp/
3. add to path to config file
   addons_path = /opt/openerp/openobject-addons/,/opt/openerp/openerp-web/addons/
4. start openerp server with my config

All works

But now I want to install new addon (aeroo reports):

1. get aeroo sources
2. place to /opt/openerp/
3. change config
   addons_path = /opt/openerp/openobject-addons/,/opt/openerp/openerp-web/addons/,/opt/openerp/aeroo/

It doesn't work

```
File "/opt/openerp/aeroo/report_aeroo/check_deps.py", line 33, in <module>
    from osv import osv
ImportError: No module named osv
```

Same thing when I try to run it from sources under windows (using eclipse+pydev)

How can I make it see modules without changing code?

```
from osv -> from openerp.osv
from tools -> from openerp.tools
```

Not first time I see module with import without leading 'openerp.'

How can i fix it ?

Comment: I think you want to run aeroo report in version 7???

Comment: you get aeroo report for version 7 from here. http://www.alistek.com/en/component/content/article/110-aeroo-reports-for-openerp-v70x.html

Comment: i used sources from https://launchpad.net/aeroo/ - it's the same

Comment: :( At my end its work perfectly i m using ubuntu. Then you have to replace osv with openerp.osv,

Comment: Changing source is not a way...

Comment: then you can do one thin go to your server ===> server==>openerp-server open file openerp-server and add the following code :         import sys
sys.path.append('openerp')

Answer (score 3):

Use this command into 7.0 openerp folder

```
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i 's/from osv/from openerp.osv/g'
```